# Create list of tuples , tuple elements taken as Input

Tags: python, list, input, tuples

I wish to create a list whose members are tuples, taken from console input. I've seen other questions which describe about tuples and lists. But how to create tuples from input and append them to list till the choice to take tuple elements is no, 'n'? I tried the following code.

```
"""
Create the tuples into a list.
"""

def createTupledList() :
    l=[]
    print("Add an element for the tuple ? y/n : ")
    ch=str(input())
    while(ch=='y') :
        print("Enter the tuple element : ")
        i=input()
        l=l.append(tuple(i))
        print("Add an element for the tuple ? y/n : ")
        ch=str(input())
    return l



l2=createTupledList()
print(l2)
```

Please help.

My inputs and error output :

```
C:\Users\vikranth\myproject\Python\Lists\Day 0>py tuplesortlist.py
Add an element for the tuple ? y/n :
y
Enter the tuple element :
1
Add an element for the tuple ? y/n :
y
Enter the tuple element :
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuplesortlist.py", line 19, in <module>
    l2=createTupledList()
  File "tuplesortlist.py", line 12, in createTupledList
    l=l.append(tuple(i))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Should the tuple contain only one element?

Comment: What is the sample tuple you are trying to input?

Comment: @Fejs, it should take the given elements, any number.

Comment: @voidpro, the tuple shoud take strings and numbers. anything should go.

Comment: Please provide an input and expected output. Something like: in: 12 out: (12,) or in: 12 out: (1,2) we don’t know what you’re trying to accomplish

Comment: And where do You start new tuple? You're close, just need to add logic to separate tuples.

Comment: `.append` is an in-place operation..... get rid of the `l=` part

Comment: @abccd, I tried :  t=tuple(i)
        l=l.append(t), but in vain.

Comment: got it, replacing l=l.append(tuple(i)) with l.append(tuple(i)) statement. And what to do if we need more than 1 element into the tuple?

Comment: @Babu split the input like `l.append(tuple(i.split(" ")))` where the input would be `1 2`

Comment: @voidpro, its working with your statement to take any input type, but its only  being the first element of the tuple. Also please let me know how to add number of elements into a tuple by choice, "ch" ? I mean, the tuple should keep on adding elements into it until our choice is no, ch='n'.

Comment: @Babu. Code written as answer. Change your question accordingly to help other readers also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `append()` function does not return an appended list, it returns a `NoneType` because it performs the append *in place*, so you can simply change the line:

```
l=l.append(tuple(i))
```

to:

```
l.append(tuple(i))
```

and this should work.

Comment: Please let me know how to add number of elements into a tuple by choice, "ch" ? I mean, the tuple should keep on adding elements into it until our choice is no, ch='n'.  Your solution is allowing only single element into a tuple.

Comment: @Babu Tuples can't be changed dynamically. You can't "add" to a tuple. You can initiate the tuple with some values and retrieve them. Think of tuples like non-dynamic arrays you might have seen in C and other languages. To achieve dynamic functionality you either use a `list` or create a new tuple with elements from the old tuple plus new elements.

Comment: @Babu further reading http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html

Comment: @Babu what @Euphe said is exactly right. But you could try to parse your input using something like `l.append(tuple(i.split(',')))` which would take the inputs `1,2,3`, `4`, `5,6` and produce the result `[('1', '2', '3'), ('4',), ('5', '6')]` But please note that more sophisticated parsing of user input is required for anything more than a personal script. I would definitely not recommend this for production code because it would be too prone to errors.

Comment: @Euphe, Thank you.

Comment: @DatHydroGuy, Understood clearly. Also can u suggest any good reference for systematic coding rules of python style. This request is out of topic for my primary question. Thanks in advance DatHydroGuy.

Answer (score 0):

Code to add multiple elements into a tuple and to add multiple tuples to a list.

```
"""
Create the tuples into a list.
"""

def createTupledList() :
    l=[]
    while True:
      t=tuple()
      print("Add an element for the tuple ? y/n : ")
      if input()!='y':
        break
      else:
        print("Keep adding the tuple elements : (x to break)")
        while True:
          i=input()
          if i=='x':
            break
          else:
            t+=(i,)
          print(t)
        l.append(t)
    return l

l2=createTupledList()
print(l2)
```

Comment: I changed the statement print("Add an element for the tuple ? y/n : ") to print("Add  tuple to the  list? y/n : ") . Hence everything is as desired.

Comment: @Babu Great! Happy coding!